# TypeError: fn is not a function. Difference between two functions in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use function from other file to make asyn/await wrap for routing. Details:

- everything works without wrap function
- second func with time works fine with similar code of export
- wrap function works fine when located in users file

Question: What have I missed and how make wrap work from server file? Thanks for hint in advance.

server.js

```
let express = require('express');
let userRules = require('./private/routes/users');
app.use('/user', userRules);

function asyncWrap(fn) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
    };
}
function getCurrentTime() {
  return getDateTime(); //inner func
}
exports.getCurrentTime= getCurrentTime;
exports.asyncWrap = asyncWrap;
```

users.js

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
const server = require('../../server');
router.post('/auth', server.asyncWrap(async (req, res, next) => { //this line throws error
    let user = await sql.getUserByEmail(req.body.email); 
    console.log(server.getCurrentTime()+req.body.email+" tried to auth"); // this works
    ...
}));
```

Error

```
TypeError: server.asyncWrap is not a function
18|dev     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/gowarranty/serverNode/forfun/private/routes/users.js:145:54)
18|dev     |     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
18|dev     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
18|dev     |     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
18|dev     |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
18|dev     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
18|dev     |     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
18|dev     |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
18|dev     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/gowarranty/serverNode/forfun/private/routes/index.js:11:13)
18|dev     |     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
18|dev     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
18|dev     |     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
18|dev     |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
18|dev     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
18|dev     |     at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
18|dev     |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
18|dev     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/gowarranty/serverNode/forfun/server.js:5:14)
18|dev     |     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
18|dev     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
18|dev     |     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
18|dev     |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
18|dev     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
18|dev     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:78:21)
18|dev     |     at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
18|dev     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
18|dev     |     at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
18|dev     |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
18|dev     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
18|dev     |     at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
18|dev     |     at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
18|dev     |     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
18|dev     |     at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

Comment: Can you `console.log` your server object in the `users.js`. Code looks fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr

you have a circular dependency issue. `server.js` requires `users.js` and `users.js` again requires the `server.js`.

The way nodeJS modules work, the `require()` call loads the file, and executes it after wrapping it in a function, passing it the module, exports and some other parameters. The module/exports is already cached for the module name, even before the file execution is complete. After execution the code in your file ends up assigning various objects associated with keys on `module.exports` or `exports`.

Now, in your case, the execution starts from `server.js` which requires `users.js` on line 2. The control passes on to `users.js` which requires `server.js` again on line 3. Then tries to call `server.asyncWrap`, but that key would be assigned to exports only on line 14 in `server.js`. The control for that file is still blocked on line 2. Hence accessing the key returns undefined (which is not a function).

There are multiple ways you can solve this.

One) You can design your code in such a manner that there are no circular dependencies. Perhaps by moving your asyncWrap function to a helper file elsewhere.

Two) You can move line two and three from `server.js` to end of the file, new file should look something like this:

```
let express = require('express');

function asyncWrap(fn) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
    };
}
function getCurrentTime() {
  return getDateTime(); //inner func
}
exports.getCurrentTime= getCurrentTime;
exports.asyncWrap = asyncWrap;

let userRules = require('./private/routes/users');
app.use('/user', userRules);`
```

While the second option would work too, I would strongly suggest using the first option.

Comment: I thought about circular dpendencies, however cannot realize why other functions work in these conditions. I think the problem is in usage in middlewares that are compiled from the start. Thank you for offering options. I agree that the first is better.

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports` It is the object reference that gets returned from the require() calls.
`exports` is just a convenience variable so module authors can write less code
Read [this](http://%20https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-module-exports-vs-exports-ec7e254d63ac) article. You will have a better understanding about creating your own modules and working with node.

Comment: I know that exports is just shortcut. But writing module.exports doesn't solve the problem of using function, isn't it?

Comment: It should solve your problem. Right now the ````asyncWrap```` function is not returned by the ``require('../../server');``. try this ``module.exports = { getCurrentTime, asyncWrap }``